# split the string of \" into array

Tags: c#, regex

I have a complex string that has lots of rubbish in it but whose structure is essentially

```
"\"test\"  \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\"\"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \" test \"";
```

I want to split all strings between the `\"` into an array of 27 elements. When i use my regex `String[] waddup = Regex.Split(test, "\"\\s+\"");` it nearly does it but leaves a trailing `\"`.

Expected Array after split:

> string[] expectedResult = new string[3] {"test", "--test", "test", "--test", "test", "--test", "test", "--test", "test", "--test", "test", "--test", "test"
>   "--test", "test", "--test", "test", "--test", "test"};

Any ideas how to cleanly do this?

Comment: Can you post the output you obtain and the wanted output?

Comment: @Piero Alberto Sure thing ....

Comment: @Fearghal what do you mean?

Comment: I mean i will post what your request intot he Quaestion

Comment: It looks like the string you posted has an extra un-escaped double quote.

Comment: Why not just use `string.Split` on double quote and take the results with an odd numbered index?

Comment: becuase that doesnt seem as clean as a good regex

Comment: Please check [this code](http://ideone.com/rC9Syn) and decide which is cleaner.

Comment: @wiktor Stribizew....smashed it. That works a treat. Put that as an answer please and il mark as closed. Also, I made it convert it to a String[] and not a var so add that in and il close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you prefer to use a regex to *match* the strings inside double quotes, you may consider:

```
string line = "\"test\"  \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\"\"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \" test \"";
// or    splts = Regex.Matches(line, "(?:^|\\s)\"([^\"]*)\"")
string[] splts = Regex.Matches(line, "\"([^\"]+)\"")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(p=>p.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

This way, with `.ToArray()`, `splts` will be a variable of type `string[]`. See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/rC9Syn).

There are 2 regexps I can suggest, the shortest is `\"([^\"]+)\"`:

- `\"` - matches a leading `"`
- `([^\"]+)` - matches and captures one or more characters other than `"`
- `\"` - matches a trailing `"`

Comment: **NOTE**: I assume there are no empty values inside `"` with `"\"([^\"]+)\""`. If there can be empty values, use `"(?:^|\\s)\"([^\"]*)\""` that also assumes the quoted values are separated with spaces.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use *string.Split* using *StringSplitOptions* to remove empty entries (if your intent is to get all the *test* strings):

```
var waddup = test.Split(new[] { "\\\"" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

With a complete console example:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var line = "\"test\"  \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"test\"\"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \"test\" \"--test\" \"--test\" \" test \"";
        var splts = line.Split(new[]{"\\\""}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", splts));
    }
}
```